# Android "Switcher" built into API?

Tags: android, api

I have completed my previous project and have decided to move onto something that is going to be a lot harder and will build on existing functionalities I have learnt whilst introducing new ones.

I want to build a hub for notes, reminders and a standard calendar view (where reminders are like checkboxed items you can cross off, and notes allow for free text).

The first thing I was wondering, was whether an 'Activity' switcher was available in the API or whether one could be implemented.
I don't know what this would be called in order to search it myself (it took a long time to realise a 'pop up window' was actually referred to as 'Dialog' within android).

http://www.trickytweaks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/top-10-hidden-jelly-bean-android-dial-codes-.png

This image shows what I am talking about, the top of the screen shows three symbols that when clicked go to different parts of the application.

I would like to build something similar (perhaps at the bottom, akin to iOS), and have the three icons move between notes, reminders or calendar.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible you could implement that with some tabs and a fragment pager. For the tabs you could start looking at ActionBarSherlock:
 http://actionbarsherlock.com

And for the "Activity Switcher" you can take a look at this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: TABS! The magic word I was looking for. Cheers for the other information !